# ajax update not working with titile attribute

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use this link :

```
 <?php echo $this->Html->link('Home',
 array('controller'=>'PurchasesOrders','action'=>'report'),array('id'=>"po",
 'data-placement'=>"top" ));?>
```

Here is my ajax code:

```
function PoNotification(){

   $('#po').removeAttr('title');

    var data = '';
    var url  = '';

    url  = '<?php echo $this->Html->url(array( 'controller' => 'PurchasesOrders', 'action' => 'purchases_orders_notification')) ;?>';

    $.ajax({
                    type     : "get",
                    url      : url,
                    dataType : 'json',

                    error    : function(resp){

                    },

                    success : function(resp){
                               $('#po').attr('title', resp.po);
                               $('#po').tooltip({trigger: 'manual'}).tooltip('show');        
                    }

            });           
     }

        setInterval(PoNotification, 5000);    
        $(function(){
            PoNotification();
        });
```

The problem is that the title value of #po remains same on each time when ajax loaded. It shows only the last value.

here is a sample fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/793vmspg/6/

Comment: instead of `prop()` could you try `attr()`?

Comment: Hi on top you are using $('#po').removeAttr('title'); and botoom you are trying  $('#po').prop('title', resp.po);     (removeAttr , prop) so try attr

Comment: Are you sure that the AJAX call is working correctly, and that `resp.po` has the value you expect?

Comment: i have tried both prop() & attr()

Comment: "*problem is that the title value of #po remains same*" - **exactly** how are you asserting that the title value remains the same?   Are you looking at the source?  Using browser inspect element?  Or actually pointing at the element and seeing the tooltip?   A simple fiddle shows attr/prop are interchangeable and both set the tooltip correctly.  https://jsfiddle.net/m8rjwunq/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/793vmspg/6/ check this a sample fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Do try using .attr()

```
$('#po').attr('title', resp.po);
```

If it doesn't work still, I suggest you debug resp.po to see what value it carries.

```
console.log(resp.po);
alert(resp.po);
```

and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution :

```
 $('#po').tooltip({trigger: 'manual'}).tooltip('destroy');
```

Use this before ajax load.